# Store files with Japanese characters in file name in msysgit

Tags: windows, git, msysgit, non-ascii-characters

I'm using a German Windows XP and created a file name with Japanese characters in the name (`どうもありがとうミスターロボット.txt`) using the Windows explorer. msysgit console just shows question marks:

```
$ git version
git version 1.7.2.3.msysgit.0

$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       ????????????????.txt
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

What should I do to make msysgit handle this file?

Answer (score 1):

[Issue 374](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=374) of msysgit refers to:

- [issue 358](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=358) (about switching the codepage used in a DOS windows)
- [issue 369](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=369) (about installing a console window to use a True Type font)

So maybe the options discussed in those threads can help here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it does not help me. `chcp 1252` (BTW, what codepage should I use for German AND Asian characters?) does not work in the git-bash (`cmd /c chcp 1252` opens a windows shell) and I already use a true type font which is capable of showing Asian characters.

Comment: @mklhmnn (not tested) from the new dos shell (with the chcp 1252), could you try to execute a bash session?

Comment: I'm using the 7zip bundle of msysgit and added `chcp 1252` to the `git-bash.bat` before the `call %COMSPEC% /c %BIN%bash --login -i` line. It shows the message that the code page 1252 is now set, but the file names still are just question marks. :(

Comment: @mklhmnn ok, interesting. And with chcp 932 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_932), just out of curiosity, what that would give you?